# gulp running watch task only first time

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, ecmascript-6, gulp-watch

I already have the watch task setup for all js/css/html etc

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
module.exports = function ()
{
    return gulp.watch([
            'www/js/**/*.js*',
            'www/css/**/*.css*',
            'www/index.html',
            '!www/bundle.js'
        ],
        ['watchify']);
};
```

as I mentioned, first time I save a file the watch task runs successfully and auto-refreshes the browser, second time onwards it does not work.
no errors but the terminal gets stuck at

> [17:10:04] Starting 'watchify'...

- node version = v5.0.0
- npm version = 3.3.12

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

to answer my own question...
looks like there was an issue with local vs global versions of modules dependency installed.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "async": "^1.4.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.1",
    "babelify": "^6.1.3",
    "brfs": "^1.4.0",
    "browserify": "^11.0.1",
    "closurecompiler": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-closure-compiler": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "lodash.assign": "^3.2.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.3.1"
  },
```

initially I had a script running to install everything globally

> "scripts": {
>       "setup": "npm install -g gulp babel-eslint eslint && npm install",

I just removed all local references of node_modules and re-installed locally and am now making sure everything is served from the app itself.
that seems to work: (happy days)

> "scripts": {
>       "setup": "npm install gulp babel-eslint eslint && npm install",

unable to +1 my own answer so *[pats myself on the back]* instead